# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')( Existing solution dint help)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, mern

I have checked other answers but that dint help.

I am not able to understand why this error is coming. I have checked api by running postman and it is giving proper data. Also I have checked my variables. what could be the possible reason for this error.
below is the code.

```
const RestaurentList = () => {
      const {restaurants , setRestaurents } = useContext(RestaurentsContext)
      useEffect(async () => {
          const fetchData= async ()=>{
              try{
                  const response = await RestaurentFinder.get("/")
                  setRestaurents(response.data.restaurants)
                  console.log(response);
              }catch(err) { }
          };
        fetchData();
      }, [])
   
    return (
        <div className="list-group">
            <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
               <thead>
                   <tr className="bg-primary">
                      <th scope="col">Restaurent </th>
                      <th scope="col">Location</th>
                      <th scope="col">Price Range</th>
                      <th scope="col">Ratings</th>
                      <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   {restaurants.map((restaurant)=>{
                       return (
                           <tr>
                               <td>{restaurant.name}</td>
                               <td>{restaurant.location}</td>
                               <td>{"$".repeat(restaurant.price_range)}</td>
                               <td>{restaurant.reviews}</td>
                               <td>
                               <button className="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                               </td>
                               <td>
                               <button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> 
                               </td>
                               
                           </tr>
                       );                       
                         })}             
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
export default RestaurentList
```

output of API:-

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "results": 1,
    "data": {
        "restaurants": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Mcdonalds",
                "location": "Hyderabad",
                "price_range": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this is the error I am getting.
[image]

Comment: If you `console.log(restaurants)` before map you will see is undefined.

Comment: always follow this format: `typeof stateName !== 'undefined' ? doSomethingHere : null`

Answer (score 1):

So `response.data` is the object coming from your fetch tool (axios prob.). You need to reach the restaurants like this;

```
const response = await RestaurentFinder.get("/");
const restaurantResult = response.data;
setRestaurents(restaurantResult.data.restaurants);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is initial value for `restaurants`? Your request is asynchronous, but the render is not. You need to wait for data to be fetched.  One way to do it is to show some spinner:

```js
const { restaurants, setRestaurents, loading, setLoading } =
  useContext(RestaurentsContext);

useEffect(async () => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await RestaurentFinder.get("/");

      setRestaurents(response.data.restaurants);
    } catch (err) {
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);

if (loading) {
  return <span>Loading...</span>
}
```

or you can have default value for `restaurants` - `[]`
or just check for undefined:

```js
{restaurants?.map(/* ... */)}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you are using axios as HTTP module:

```
 const {response : { data : { restaurants } }} = await
    RestaurentFinder.get("/");
    setRestaurents(restaurants);
```

> If You are using Fetch

```
 const response  = await RestaurentFinder.get("/");
 const {response : { data : { restaurants } }} = await response.json();
    setRestaurents(restaurants);
```